# Enable Sony camera and mic unit for Mac

Tags: macbook-pro, webcam

Is there any way I can use Sony cmu-br100 on a Mac? I couldn't find any drivers on the website. So wanted to know if there is any way around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try just plugging it in? macOS has built-in support for a lot of standard USB device classes, so custom drivers aren’t required for devices that comply with those standards. A quick search showed that that product claims to support standard USB audio device classes for the mics, but I don’t know about the camera.

So plug it in and see if the mics show up in System Preferences > Sound > Input. Then run your intended video app and see if the camera shows up there.

Comment: Oh man. You're right. It worked.